Ошибка "Не удалось создать новую виртуальную машину. 'Новая виртуальная машина' не удалось реализовать" при попытке создать VM в Hyper-V

Ранее виртуальные машины в Hyper-V создавались без проблем. Использую тот же образ, что и ранее, однако с недавнего времени стала возникать ошибка, прикрепил скриншот
